# NoMethodError in Passwords#edit in Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in ruby on rails and got an error with this. When I add for feature to render a template, it didn't change anyway.

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p44y.png)

[edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwyGr.png)

[pass controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq6r2.png)

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H549w.png)

Comment: You use `form.object.errors.any?` and Rails complain that `object` is nil. But what is `object` ? I am not an expert in forms but to me there is no default child as "object" for forms. If you want to catch the errors in your form, you should just infer the object that you create in the controller, whatever it's name is. Probably `@user` with something like `@user.errors.any?`

Comment: Great ! thanks for help... it's solved

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a `@user` on the controller action.
On the update action, you need to do something like this:

```
@user = Current.user
```